# Use of Annotations with the @Target set as TYPE

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to figure out the use of the TARGET being set as TYPE.
    import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
    import java.lang.annotation.Target;
    import java.util.Map;

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@interface A1 {
}

@A1
class Y {}

class X {
     void foo() {
         Map<@A1 Y, String> y1; // ERROR: The Annotation is disallowed at the
                                    // location
     }
}
```

The [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) lists:
ElementType.TYPE can be applied to any element of a class.

Does it mean it can be applied to the fields of the class. If that is the case I can 
set the @Target to @Target ({ ElementType.FIELD }).

Why would i need ElementType.TYPE.

[JSR 308](http://types.cs.washington.edu/jsr308/specification/java-annotation-design.html#type-annotation-locations) lists

> A type annotation appears before the type’s simple name, as in @NonNull String or java.lang.@NonNull String. Here are examples:

```
for generic type arguments to parameterized classes:

  Map<@NonNull String, @NonEmpty List<@Readonly Document>> files;
```

So the question is where the target type set as ElementType.TYPE is useful and
that would also probably answer me getting a error.

Comment: You missunderstood ElementType.TYPE. It mean any Java Type that is class or interface

Comment: If I understand correctly the Oracle documentation, `ElementType.TYPE` mean that it can be apply to all element where other types can be applied.

Comment: @Shekhar

\@A1
class Y {}

The annotation is on class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm ... the explanation in the tutorial

```
ElementType.TYPE can be applied to any element of a class
```

is indeed wrong. I also understand the phrase "any element of a class", as if you can place this annotation on any member. This is wrong.

This is the Javadoc comment for [`ElementType.TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE):

```
Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration
```

It is speaking about type declaration. Nothing else. As per the other usage scenarios you mentioned, have a look at Java 8 (hey, it's out since two days). The [`ElementType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) enumeration now knows two additional constants: `TYPE_PARAMETER` and `TYPE_USE`. I think, that is what you had in mind.

Comment: As per JSR 308 I can declare something like this:
Map<@NonNull String, @NonEmpty List<@Readonly Document>> files;

Then why do I get a error with
Map<@A1 Y, String> y1;

Thanks

Comment: JSR 308 extends Java’s annotation system [Blo04] so that annotations may appear on any use of a type. (By contrast, Java SE 7 permits annotations only on declarations; JSR 308 is backward-compatible and continues to permit those annotations.)

Answer (score 0):

The given definition

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@interface A1 {
}
```

creates a declaration annotation that can only be placed on declarations (in particular, on the definition of a class, interface, or enum).

To create a type annotation that can be placed on any use of a type (as opposed to only on the definition of a type), change TYPE to TYPE_USE:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE_USE })
@interface A1 {
}
```